# Reference of saying of Sayyedna Umer(May Allah be Pleased with him)?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, sahaba, day-of-judgement

What is the reference/link of tradition quoting Sayyedna Umer(May Allah be Pleased with him)  where he said regarding his fear of day of Judgment and i am only trying to rewrite approximate meaning only of his wording

"if i (omer(R.A)) succeeded on day of judgment by equal weights,then it will be a great achievement"